# Which structure for bit?

Tags: c++, bit

Hi have to manage a string of bit.

Which is the best way to do it?!

I know that the use of bool elements can be a good choice,
but how can be sure that a bool element uses only one bit of memory?!

I've read about bitset structure, but I've read that it uses the bool
element.

Comment: `bool` usually is one byte in size.

Comment: just use an array of <insert primitive type here> and bitmasking.

Comment: have you looked at `vector<bool>`?

Comment: You can use a bunch of [bitfields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field). But if you need an arbitrary (but defined at compile time) amount of bits, just use a [bitset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset). Otherwise, `vector<bool>` is often specialized for this purpose.

Comment: `std::bitset` is absolutely fine for this case, especially the i/o interworking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

class template `std::bitset` and several related functions are used for representing and manipulating fixed-size sequences of bits. Each bit represent either 1 or 0. This class does not use bool type to represent bits. If you need a container that will contain bool values you can consider `std::vector<bool>`. It is a specialization of template `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices, really:

- with a reasonable upper-bound of the number of bits, `std::bitset<N>` where `N` is the number of bits is very handy
- otherwise, a `std::vector<unsigned char>` on top of which you code bit placement is probably best

*Note: `std::vector<bool>` implements this bit-packing for you, so you might use it, however the main issue with it is that `at` for example will yield a proxy instead of a `bool&` because of this bit-packing and this can confuse templated code.*

Answer (score 0):

you can use bitset.

You might want to take a look at this. it states :

> The class emulates an array of bool elements, but optimized for space
>   allocation: generally, each element occupies only one bit (which, on
>   most systems, is eight times less than the smallest elemental type:
>   char).
>
> Each bit position can be accessed individually: for example, for a
>   given bitset named foo, the expression foo[3] accesses its fourth bit,
>   just like a regular array accesses its elements.

from this link: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/

Answer (score 0):

`vector<bool>` MAY store all values as bits, while providing most of the functionality of a regular vector.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector-bool/